# Apache2 - Only files with a specific extension can be downloaded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2

I've set a virtual directory in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default like so:

```
    Alias /lynx/ "/home/srv1100/"
    <Directory "/home/srv1100/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

every file is accessible when I write http://127.0.0.1/lynx/... I want that only files, which their extension is NOT "bsp" or "nav" and will be accessible. I can't put them in other directory.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to do this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.(bsp|nav)$ - [nocase,gone,last]
```

Comment: Ahh, mod_rewrite...is there anything you can't do?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the mod_autoindex documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Check out the IndexIgnore directive.

Comment: This prevents the files from showing up in the autoindex, but does not prevent a user from typing in the filename on the URL line and downloading them.  You can accomplish the latter via file permissions (or creative use of mod_rewrite).

Comment: Yeah, I missed that :(.  Use file permissions to do it quickly, mod_rewrite to do it correctly.

Just as an aside, you may want to look at your architecture/design a little bit regarding these files.  If you don't want people downloading them, then why are they in a webroot?  If you're including them in pages then permissions are going to break your site and you'll have to use mod_rewrite.  If they're not included in your content, then why are they there?  Just some food for thought.